# Is it possible to get a colour name in iOS based on RGB values?

Tags: ios, colors

I want to get a colour name based on some RGB values. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It is not a trivial task http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It is possible.

It is enough to prepare a list of colors tagged with names in RGB. Then find the color that is nearest by some metric. Euclidean distance will do.

There is an article from [xkcd](http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/) with a color survey. They even give you the survey database to fiddle around with. Quality of data is not guaranteed but a good base nevertheless.

Comment: I implemented an example using the xkcd survey results here: https://github.com/daniel-beard/DBColorNames